# How define in validate () groups: { checks } with 3 different Checkbox groups?

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-plugins, checkbox, jquery-validate

One checkbox only works fine. But how define 3 different checkbox groups in validate() function in ->  groups: { checks: "" }

here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#item").validate({
        rules: { //some rules 
        },
        groups: {
            checks: "withe blue red",
            checks: "gas tel sat",
            checks: "cola fanta sprite"
        },
        messages: { //some messages 
        }
    });
    $.validator.addMethod('loc-sel-3', function (value) {
        return $('.char-sel-3:checked').size() > 2;
    }, '<?php _e("Please check at least 3 characteristic", "twitter"); ?>');

    $.validator.addMethod('char-sel-3', function (value) {
        return $('.char-sel-3:checked').size() > 1;
    }, '<?php _e("Please check at least 2 features", "twitter"); ?>');

    $.validator.addMethod('tech-sel-3', function (value) {
        return $('.tech-sel-3:checked').size() > 0;
    }, '<?php _e("Please check at least one box", "twitter"); ?>');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Different names.

groups: {
            color: "withe blue red",
            tech: "gas tel sat",
            drink: "cola fanta sprite"
        },